# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL php code?

Tags: php

Привет всем

```
<?php
$mars = time ();
if ($kaka == 0) {
  $html = <<<HERE 
  <div id="class">
    <div id="dialod">
      <center>

        <div id="ok_shareWidget"></div>
        <script>
     !function (d, id, did, st) {
       var js = d.createElement("script");
       js.src = "<? echo $klass22; ?>";
       js.onload = js.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") {
      if (!this.executed) {
        this.executed = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
       OK.CONNECT.insertShareWidget(id,did,st);
        }, 0);
      }
       }};
       d.documentElement.appendChild(js);
     }(document,"ok_shareWidget","http://site.ru/t3/s2.php?id=<? echo $create_id;?>","{width:125,height:50,st:'straight',sz:45,ck:1,nc:1}");

     function listenForShare() {
      if (window.addEventListener) {
       window.addEventListener('message', onShare, false);
      } else {
       window.attachEvent('onmessage', onShare);
      }
     }
     function onShare(e) {
      var args = e.data.split("$");
      if (args[0] == "ok_shared") {
     window.location="pe.php"; // Вывод идентификатора фрейма кнопки - в случае нескольких кнопок на одной странице, по нему можно определить какая именно была кликнута
       if (alert) 
       $( '#baner_grup' ).show();

       $( '.classs' ).html('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://site.ru/t/pre.php" />');

       $( '#class' ).hide();
       $( '.player' ).hide();


      }
     }
     listenForShare();
    </script>
</div>

</div>

</div>
        </div>
        <div>
        HERE;

}
else {
  $x = 0;

}
```

в чём проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

- После открытия `<<<HERE` сразу должен быть конец строки и никаких пробелов!
- Конечное `HERE;` должно быть в самом начале строки без пробелов до него! И без пробелов после него! Не должно быть лишних символов!
- точка с запятой `;` необязательна, но если она есть, то между ней и `HERE` также не должно быть лишних символов

И для закрепления материал цитата из документации (http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> **Внимание**
>
> Очень важно отметить, что строка с закрывающим идентификатором не
>   должна содержать других символов, за исключением точки с запятой (;).
>   Это означает, что идентификатор **не должен вводиться с отступом** и что
>   не может быть никаких пробелов или знаков табуляции до или после точки
>   с запятой. Важно также понимать, что первым символом перед закрывающим
>   идентификатором должен быть символ новой строки, определенный в вашей
>   операционной системе. Например, в UNIX системах, включая Mac OS X, это
>   \n. После закрывающего идентификатора также сразу должна начинаться
>   новая строка.
>
> Если это правило нарушено и закрывающий идентификатор не
>   является "чистым", считается, что закрывающий идентификатор
>   отсутствует и PHP продолжит его поиск дальше. Если в этом случае
>   верный закрывающий идентификатор так и не будет найден, то это вызовет
>   ошибку парсинга с номером строки в конце скрипта.

Также внутри `Heredoc` не надо писать `<? echo $create_id;?>`  достаточно просто подставлять переменную `$create_id`. Аналогично с `$klass22`